# Plumber welded or soldered copper pipe in basement, what would be a typical charge for 45 min of work?

Tags: plumbing

I recommended a plumber to my friend and she's a bit concerned he charged too much. SHe had a couple of leaks in a copper pipe (probably a hot water line) approx 1" diameter, and he turned off the water and then soldered or welded several sections of pipe together I think three sections of pipe were welded. I have no idea what plumbing repairs cost so Im asking you guys. He charged $200 he was there about 45 min. This is in MD suburbs of washington DC. Do you think that a fair price?

Comment: VTC as prices and how jobs are paid for vary. However sounds like a good job by the plumber.

Comment: The only way to know is to get several plumbers out for quotes. Now that the work is done, you won't get anyone out there, and if you pretend that it's still a problem, you'll probably get exorbitant quotes so you never call them again. If you felt that the plumber did a good enough job at a good enough price to recommend him to your friend, then you should be able to reassure your friend that she got a good deal.

Answer (score 7):

For time spent and travel, materials and supplies used, (solder, propane) and the expertise to diagnose the problem and repair it as well as having the needed tools and insurance....$200 is a deal.

Keep that plumbers' number.

Answer (score 5):

A house call where a plumber does **nothing** is $100. This guy identified multiple leaks in the same pipe, fixed it all in 45 minutes, and charged only $200.

I would say your friend got a really good plumber.

Would she rather the contractor dragged it out over a week and bill her $1,000? Don't look at the time it took; look at the results.